# we use api to fetch numbers between 1 to 5. For example you will get 4 as input from API then you have to activate first four anchor tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

Frist we have to create five anchor tags in that, we use api to fetch numbers between 1 to 5. For example you will get 4 as input from API then add active class to first four anchor tags and in another case like you get 3 as input then add active class to first 3 anchor tags.

```
let url = "http://localhost:3000/api/hygiene";
           let main = document.querySelector(".insert");
           let cardData = "";
           /*get request*/
           fetch(url)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                      data.forEach(function(item,index){
                      
                      cardData += `
                               <div class="card my-2 mx-2 product_card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                    <img src="http://localhost:3000/product/${item.image[0].filename}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                         <h5 class="card-title">${item.title}</h5>
                                         <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${item.category}</h6>
                                         <div class="rate ">
                                              <a href="#!">★</a>
                                              <a href="#!">★</a>
                                              <a href="#!">★</a>
                                              <a href="#!" >★</a>
                                              <a href="#!" >★</a>
                                         </div>
                                         <p class="card-text">${item.sortDescription}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body d-flex">
                                         <div class="price">
                                              <span class="before">₹${item.before}</span>
                                              <span class="current">₹${item.after}</span>
                                         </div>
                                         <a href="#${"product"+item._id}" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">more</a>
                                    </div>
                               </div>`;
           })
           main.innerHTML = cardData;
           
           })
           .catch((e)=>{
               console.log(e)
           })
```

Add class in this  tag

```
<div class="rate ">                               
   <a href="#!">★</a>                                              
   <a href="#!">★</a>                                                 
   <a href="#!">★</a>                                                 
   <a href="#!" >★</a>                                                 
   <a href="#!" >★</a>                                            </div>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I want to add given no of active class to to first given no  , ex - given value is 4 then add active class in first 4 <a> tag

Answer (score 0):

I found correct answer and its work

```
let url = "http://localhost:3000/api/hygiene"
           let main = document.querySelector(".insert");
           let module = document.querySelector(".moduls");
           let rate = document.querySelector(".rate");
           
           let star = "";
           let cardData = "";
           let detailsData = "";
           
           /*get request*/
           fetch(url)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                      data.forEach(function(item,index){
                      
                      let noStar = Number(item.star) // declare no of elements you want to add active class
                     
                      cardData += `
                               <div class="card my-2 mx-2 product_card" style="width: 18rem;">
                                    <img src="http://localhost:3000/product/${item.image[0].filename}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                         <h5 class="card-title">${item.title}</h5>
                                         <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${item.category}</h6>
                                         ${stars()} // call function to add elements
                                         <p class="card-text">${item.sortDescription}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body d-flex">
                                         <div class="price">
                                              <span class="before">₹${item.before}</span>
                                              <span class="current">₹${item.after}</span>
                                         </div>
                                         <a href="#${"product"+item._id}" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">more</a>
                                    </div>
                               </div>`;
                       
                           
                           function stars(){
                                   function starArr(){
                                           let starsArr = [];
                                           for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                                                starsArr.push(
                                                   `<a  href="#!" class="${i <= noStar ? 'active' : ''}">★ </a>`
                                                );
                                           }
                                       return starsArr.join("")
                                   }
                              return `<div class="rate ">${starArr()}</div>`;
                           }
                           
           })
           main.innerHTML = cardData;
           })
           .catch((e)=>{
               console.log(e)
           })
```

Code

Answer (score -1):

You can use the concept of conditionally rendering the element based on the value from the API

Note: I've just added a background color on the stars, you can customize it accordingly.

Here's the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mtm3nz?file=src%2FApp.js

Refer to the following code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const totalStars = 5;

const App = () => {
  const [starCount, setStarCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // make your API call here and setStarCount to the value received
    setStarCount(2); // do this after you have your result from the API
  }, []);

  const renderStars = () => {
    let starsArr = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= totalStars; i++) {
      starsArr.push(
        <a key={i} href="#!" className={i <= starCount ? 'active' : ''}>
          ★
        </a>
      );
    }
    return starsArr;
  };
  return <div className="rate ">{renderStars()}</div>;
};
export default App;
```

Comment: Just one problem. The OP isn't using React.

Comment: its ok language is different but logic remains same , Thanks